# Java Swing - programmatically copy to clipboard from a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to add a button to my UI which copies the contents of a specific table to the clipboard. I think this should be easy but I can't seem to get it to work or find the solution on the internet. I tried this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
ActionEvent nev = new ActionEvent(fileTable, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "copy");
TransferHandler.getCopyAction().actionPerformed(nev);
}
```

but it has no effect. 
What's the best way to achieve this?
Thanks,
Peter

Comment: I should say that `fileTable` is a JTable and `jButton1ActionPerformed` is the method called when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all who answered. I did some tracing through the Swing code with the debugger. I believe the code I posted and what camickr posted end up doing basically the same thing. The problem was that I assumed that 'no selection' in the table would copy everything. In fact it's a no-op - this is in BasicTableUI.java if anyone is interested. So this code does work:

```
ActionEvent nev = new ActionEvent(fileTable, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "copy");
fileTable.selectAll();
fileTable.getActionMap().get(nev.getActionCommand()).actionPerformed(nev);
```

In my actual code I've added lines to save the current selection before `selectAll()` and then restore it.

Comment: You copy my code (which does work) and accept your answer? I'll remember that the next time you post a question. By the way your code doesn't even work. It willl generate a NPE.

Comment: No, I copied my code from the question and inserted the fileTable.selectAll() line. However you are right about the NPE, I (who knows why) mis-copied the command parameter and put "" instead of "copy". Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: 'Your' code does the same as 'my' original code - it copies nothing if there's no selection. Therefore it did not answer my problem. However I did explain this in my answer and I voted your answer up, so, if you feel you have been insufficiently credited, then I feel sorry for you.

Answer (score 5):

All Swing components contain Actions that invoked by KeyStrokes. You can reuse this Action.

```
Action copy = table.getActionMap().get("copy");
ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(table, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "");
copy.actionPerformed(ae);
```

For a list of all Actions check out the [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/).